# Attempting to create a twitch.tv IRC bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, irc

I'm having a couple issues that I really do not understand; I haven't really done anything with javascript in years so I might just be missing something really simple but I have googled and googled and nothing.

```
var sys = require('util'),
    irc = require('./lib/irc'),
    pkgconfig = require('pkgconfig'),
    winston = require('winston'),
    argv = require('optimist').default('config', 'config').argv; // alternative: nconf

var confName = argv.config;

/**
 * More advanced config
 *
 *
 * 
 */
var options = {
    schema: 'config/schema.json',
    config: 'config/' + confName + '.json'
};

var config = pkgconfig(options);

var bot = new irc.Client(config.server, config.botName, {
        channels: config.channels
    });

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({ level: config.logLevel })
//      new (winston.transports.File)({ level: config.logLevel, filename: 'ircbot.log' })
    ]
});

config.logger = logger;

/**
 * Let's power up
 */

var ircClient = new irc.Server(config);
ircClient.connect();
   //Listeners

bot.addListener('join', function (channel, who) {
         // Welcome them in!
    bot.say(channel, who + "Sup dude OneHand/");
});
```

That's my code; obviously I changed the password. Everytime I node the .js file it tells me that the bot part of bot.addListener is an unexpected identifier. Help?

EDIT: Fixed some of the obvious mess-ups. Still don't understand what's wrong

EDITEDIT: Completely revamped my code and now my issue is at line 31 and whenever I try to run it under node bot.js It tells me that I have a TypeError:Undefined is not a function and it points to the keyword new. Not exactly sure why that happens.